# Ros indigo p2os_teleop not working

Tags: ros, p2os, teleop, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm new with Ros. Just started working with Pioneer P3-DX using p2os.
i installed p2os-perdue on ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Ros Indigo

1. I launched : rosrun p2os_drive p2os_drive   ( to connect to the robot)
   it seems to work, because the robot name appeared, I'am using serial port PC<->robot
   there is an annoying bipping though, i don't really know if it's normal, but i'am able to get robot motor state  with
   "rostopic echo /motor_state"
2. i launched: rosrun p2os_teleop  p2os_teleop
   No errors detected but when pressing the keyboard while on the terminal (ex: left arrow and right arrow)
   characters appears (like : [[A ) but nothing happening , robot not moving
3. I even tried with: rostopic pub /cmd_vel  geometry_msg/Twist '[0.1, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'
   still nothing, robot not moving at all :/

so please Help :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221885/ros-indigo-p2os_teleop-not-working/) by [CEAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/22107/ceas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

solve 1) and 3) by adding _pulse:=1 as argument to p2os_drive

---

Originally posted by [CEAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/22107/ceas/) with karma: 31 on 2015-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0